# Is there a way to get Firestore data to User model class in flutter then pass the data to the screens?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

There is a way to get firestore data for example " User information" into user model class in flutter?
This is my User Class:

```
class Users {
  final int id;
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String emailAddress;
  final String imageProfile;

  const Users({
    this.id,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.emailAddress,
    this.imageProfile,

  });

}

final Users currentUser = Users(
  id: 'GET_DATA_FROM_FIRESTORE'/// firebaseUSer.currentUserUID
  firstName: 'GET_DATA_FROM_FIRESTORE',
  lastName: 'GET_DATA_FROM_FIRESTORE',
  emailAddress: 'GET_DATA_FROM_FIRESTORE',
  imageProfile: 'GET_DATA_FROM_FIRESTORE',
);
```

then pass the data with  `currentUser.firstName` etc.. to other widgets.
the data I need to retrieve into this class is created into SignuUp form in flutter and pushed to firestore collection

Comment: It doesn't look like you've made an attempt to query Firestore yet.  Start with that using the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/), then once you have data from a document, it should be clear how to put that into a data class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this in my project.I hope that will helpful.

**Model Class**

```
class Message{
  String id;
  String message;
  String senderId;
  Timestamp timeStamp;
  bool isMedia;
  Message({this.id,this.message,this.senderId,this.timeStamp,this.isMedia});
  factory Message.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot){
    return Message(
      id:snapshot.id,
      message: snapshot.data()['message'],
      senderId: snapshot.data()['senderId'],
      timeStamp: snapshot.data()['timeStamp'],
      isMedia: snapshot.data()['isMedia'],
    );
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
  {
    'message': message,
    'senderId': senderId,
    'isMedia': isMedia,
    'timeStamp': DateTime.now(),
  };
}
```

**Service Class**

**Initial*

```
  final FirebaseFirestore _fBaseFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  CollectionReference _collectionRef;
  MessageService() {
    _collectionRef = _fBaseFireStore.collection('Conversation');
  }
```

**Get datas from firestore*

```
    Stream<List<Message>> getMessages(String conversationId) {
    var ref = _collectionRef
        .doc(conversationId)
        .collection('messages');
    return ref.snapshots().map(
        (event) => event.docs.map((e) => Message.fromSnapshot(e)).toList());
  }
```

**Write data to firestore*

```
  Future<void> sendMessage(Message message, String conversationId) async {
    var ref = _collectionRef.doc(conversationId).collection('messages');
    await ref.add(message.toJson());
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much what about _collectionRef ?

Comment: This is parent collection                                                                          
_fBaseFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;                                                                                        _collectionRef = _fBaseFireStore.collection('Conversation');

Comment: Could you edit the reply above with this parent as well so I understand better why I get the error?